# Is there a good source to compare academic salaries at European universities?

Tags: university, job, salary, europe

Is there a good source to compare academic salaries at European universities? For example, what are the salaries of full professors in different countries?

I would particularly welcome a possible source, a link pointing to a page where this information is available.

Comment: We could start writing down our salaries here... that would give some interesting comparison

Comment: Maybe you should reformulate the question. As it is now, this will lead to big lists, and you ask two different questions.

Comment: @Sylvain Peyronnet: Is the reformulated question better? You should edit it.

Comment: Yep, I like it now ;) I am not in favour of editing other people questions at the beginning of the beta. I prefer see before where the site is going, so that I can adapt myself.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think [this page](http://www.eui.eu/ProgrammesAndFellowships/AcademicCareersObservatory/CareerComparisons/SalaryComparisons.aspx) has what you are looking for. As far as I can tell (e.g. for France) the numbers are fine.

However, we should keep in mind that the comparison can be made difficult. For instance, "full professor" is not an actual rank in french academia. You are either a "maitre de conférences" (roughly equivalent to assistant prof. position to "junior" associate prof.), then "professeur des universités" (roughly from more senior associate prof. to full prof.).

Comment: It would also be better if there were more information about benefits. Also, the data there isn't entirely correct (Germany's is out of date and also misrepresented—the salary for an assistant professor is about 3900€ per month).

Comment: I think these figures should only be taken as rough guidelines as the differences within a country can be larger than between two different countries. In the UK for example, while two people may be on the same position in the pay scale, the actual amount that is paid may differ from university to university. Then there are regional pecularities like an extra allowance for London universities.

Comment: Great link. However, since these figures stand for *gross* salaries, the page should be complemented with taxation information. Here's what I found for Europe: http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/tedb/taxSearch.html

Answer (score 17):

http://www.glassdoor.com/ works by getting anonymous information from users and sharing it. It is really vast and accurate as far as I am aware.

Examples:
TA: Brigham Young University $10.41/hour
Professor: University of Warwick: £103/year-£112/year

You must only Select Salaries on the dropdown menu, add a description or phrase of the position and/or location.

Comment: nice, actually I even found a salary from a software engineer in Vietnam. Didn't expect that. Actually (in case of: Sotware Engineer Switzerland) those lists show only better paid jobs from international firms. Sure not every developer gets paid 100k per year, as their data shows. Unfortunately they force you to sign in, after 2-3 searches :/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to get information about different countries, but [this webpage](http://www.gehaltsvergleich.com) allows you to query the information on salaries in different parts of Germany. If you query for "professor" you will find several categories depending upon the status of the academic institution (University, University of applied sciences (Fachhochschule) etc.). [Here](http://www.gehaltsvergleich.com/gehalt/Professor-Professorin-Wissenschaftliche-Hochschulen.html) is the link to the salaries of full professor in normal universities.

Comment: For Germany, [Öffentlicher Dienst](http://oeffentlicher-dienst.info) is a much more accurate source of information.

Answer (score 0):

For Germany the best website to see professor salaries is the following:
https://www.academics.de/wissenschaft/w-besoldung-2014-eine-uebersicht-der-grundgehaelter_56973.html

It gives the W1, W2, and W3 Professor ranges. Just keep in mind that it is not strictly comparable to an assist, assoc, full ranking as W2 is considered also a full professor. Also, there is not tenure track system in Germany, although a couple universities are starting to experiment with it so you can have a permanent or temporary contract that may become permanent in the future or may not.