# Leveraging offers

Tags: tenure-track, lecturer, negotiation, politics, promotion

I am currently working as a full time lecturer after two years of unemployment post disatorous tenure denial.  I have two on campus visits lined up for associate professor positions.  The lecturer position I currently have was advertised as an assistant/associate position which I applied for initially.  The Dean asked me to apply for the lecturer position because she wanted to offer another candidate (different specialty) the tt position.  Turns out the other candidate was abd and the provost insisted on hiring that position as a lecturer until dissertation was completed.  Other candidate not only has not completed dissertation but teaching performance was so poor that they have decided not to renew contract.  Meanwhile, my concentration has exploded with quadruplethe number of students from previous year.  My teaching evaluations were glowing and they have offered another year as a lecturer.  I want to reopen the possibility hiring on tt track and promotion to Associate before I get counter offers from campus visits.  Pretty sure the Dean wants to keep me as a mule but the Provost might have very different ideas.  Any advice on strategy?

***addendum***

1. The plan is to rehire next year but the position is open now.
2. I do not have offers now but I am a finalist for two separate positions, campus visits this week.  I would like to give the Dean a letter now requesting negotiation to get the idea on the table.  I'm assured work as a lecturer, want to float the possibility of getting more.
3. ***There may be a more general question you could ask, such as “What factors determine whether a university will consider its non-TT lecturers for a TT position?”*** Noted, will consider.

Comment: This will depend on the country, the field, the University, the persons you are talking to… You are looking for an advice no random stranger on the Internet can give you, I'm afraid. You are including aspects that are irrelevant to your question ("I am currently working … tenure denial." and "Meanwhile, my concentration … previous year. "), which makes it hard to understand what exactly is your question. Maybe you are really asking [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/4807/how-should-an-academic-negotiate-his-her-salary)?

Comment: Are they rehiring the line right now? Or is it on hold for hiring next year? I think it makes a difference, because of hiring policies. Furthermore, it may matter the general type of institution...

Comment: There may be a more general question you could ask, such as “What factors determine whether a university will consider its non-TT lecturers for a TT position?”

Comment: Wait, the title says “leveraging offers,” but the text says you have visits, not offers. Please clarify.

Comment: I don't feel confident in this as an answer, but I would expect that that the school can't hire you without a full search. So at the most you will get big promises that you will be the top choice for the position next year. Then next year you will have a decent shot at the position, but you will also have the drawbacks of an inside hire. If you get another position, I would take it (bird in the hand worth two in the bush, etc.).

Comment: But what is your ultimate goal?  Do you have some particular reason for wanting to stay where you are? After your bitter experience, I'd imagine you'd want to leave. // Typically, leverage is done with a bird in the hand (not in the bush). // In general, if a candidate has been bumped out of the tenure track, it's probably better to try ot get back into a tenure track position *elsewhere*.